# Using Django-Filter for a Many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

Essentially, I've been using Django-Filter to filter a large list of publications on various fields. One field is keywords, which has a many-to-many relationship through a **PublicationKeywords** table. The models look as follows (withholding certain fields and information):

```
class Publication(models.Model):
 keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, through='PublicationKeywords')

class Keyword(models.Model):
 value = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class PublicationKeywords(models.Model):
 keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, db_column='keyword_id',
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                null=True)
 publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, db_column='publication_id',
                                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    null=True)
```

Is it possible to use a **ModelChoiceFilter** or **ModelMultipleChoiceFilter** in this case to do something similar to

```
PublicationKeywords.objects.filter(keyword__value_in=keyword_list).distinct('publication')
```

Basic filter set up looks as follows

```
class PublicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    state = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    sac = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Sac.objects.all())
    published_date_after = DateFilter(
        field_name='published_date', lookup_expr=('gte'))
    published_date_before = DateFilter(
        field_name='published_date', lookup_expr=('lte'))
    data_begin_year = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        lookup_expr='gte')
    data_end_year = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        lookup_expr='lte')
    keywords = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=?)
    # TODO figure out how to get this keywords filter to work like
    # PublicationKeywords.objects.filter(keyword__value_in=keyword_list).distinct('publication')

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        strict = False
        fields = ['title', 'state', 'sac', 'published_date',
                  'data_begin_year', 'data_end_year', 'keywords']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PublicationFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.data == {}:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.none()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there was a simpler solution, but I could not get Django-Filter to properly filter by multiple keywords, so I altered my views.py. A little bit hacky, but since the keywords were captured properly in the querystring, it was simple enough to grab those values and put them into a list through self.request.GET, and then conditionally set the queryset passed in PublicationFilter.

```
keyword_list = []
        try:
            keyword_list = self.request.GET['keywords'].split(", ")
        except:
            pass
        if len(keyword_list) > 1:
            filter_list = PublicationFilter(
                self.request.GET, queryset=Publication.objects.filter(keywords__value__in=keyword_list).distinct())
        else:
            filter_list = PublicationFilter(
                self.request.GET, queryset=Publication.objects.all())

        paginator = Paginator(filter_list.qs, 10)
```